# I am not able to ctrl + click on feature file in Cucumber step definition, definition not found error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, cucumber, maven

****Help Me****

I have installed Cucumber and Natural but my feature file is not getting highlighted after clicking `ctrl + click`.

Also, it has highlighted with yellow color

While running Test Runner, it says initialization error: Method 'initializationError' not found. Opening the test class.

How to fix this issue? I looked the solved answers related to same but still getting the same issue. I am not able to find setting under file? Please specify which file setting? Is it project level?

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Cucumber Eclipse Plugin from Eclipse Marketplace;
2. Once the plugin is installed, Create a feature file;
3. Right Click on Project -> Configure -> Convert to Cucumber project;
4. Now try Ctrl + Click on any step from feature file.

Answer (score 0):

select all the feature lines & right click > open with > Editor. Then ctrl + click on the line

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how your suggestion will solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Faced this before & following **solution works for me**:

- Install plugin "**BDD Goto Step**" from marketplace
- After installation is might ask to **restart the IDE**. [If not its **recommended** to reflect changes]
- Now if you **press Ctrl & click on any step**, it will **take you to definition of particular step**